# How to localize / internationalize database for different languages? - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, database, localization

For example, there is an entity "**book**" with the attributes "**title**" and "**description**".

There are plenty books stored in the database. The information is stored in english. Now I'd like to publish this app in e.g. 10 different countries (10 different languages).

Is there any way to handle this with **NSLocalized*** or is it necessary to **extend** the **database**, that every stored entity must be created for each language?

I think when doing this with a Localizable file, it gets unbelievable huge and chaotic.

What is the **best practice** for this?

Answer (score 1):

My first question is will this data change during the life of the app? If the answer is yes, then you will encounter issues with NSLocalized because you would have to update the app to include translated strings.

Otherwise, maintaining 10 different databases is a recipe for disaster. A few quick searches can cover this in agonizing detail.

Assuming then that the data will be static with each release, I would recommend that you take a different approach and create a single `books.plist` file that contains your data. This gives you the benefit of being able to localize the file, without the need to maintain a separate strings file to feed into your localization calls. Using this approach requires just one source of truth and supports your localization needs. Additionally, if you support copying it into the users documents directory, it can also be updated over time as your list evolves.

Comment: Thanks first! No the data won't change and its static with each release. It could happen that there must be taken some corrections, but this is something else. So I will take a look at your .plist approach. I have no idea how to deal with this until now